# Python 3.5.2 images2gif type error

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am experiencing errors with using images2gif on python3.5.2.

I have already experienced a few issues which I found answers for, but havent seen this problem documented anywhere.

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
from images2gif import writeGif
import urllib.request

image_files=["list of png image files in the same directory as the script"]

images = [Image.open(fn) for fn in image_files]

gif_file = "test-gif.GIF"
writeGif(gif_file, images, duration=44)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-75192c4aeed1> in <module>()
      7 
      8 gif_file = "test-gif.GIF"
----> 9 writeGif(gif_file, images, duration=44)

C:\Users\mchoy2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\images2gif\images2gif.py in writeGif(filename, images, duration, repeat, dither, nq, subRectangles, dispose)
    591     fp = open(filename, 'wb')
    592     try:
--> 593         gifWriter.writeGifToFile(fp, images, duration, loops, xy, dispose)
    594     finally:
    595         fp.close()

C:\Users\mchoy2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\images2gif\images2gif.py in writeGifToFile(self, fp, images, durations, loops, xys, disposes)
    446 
    447                 # Write
--> 448                 fp.write(header)
    449                 fp.write(globalPalette)
    450                 fp.write(appext)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Edit: Updated with full error message**

Comment: Could you post a little more of the stack trace? I suspect you're seeing a Python 2 vs. Python 3 problem (I see the library hasn't been updated since 2013 when Python 3 wasn't as popular).

Comment: @AlexTaylor Added the full error as displayed in my notebook

Answer (score 0):

Error message is showing because images2gif is made for python 2.x not 3.x